# In Google Analytics How to include blank rows in a report with many dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-webmasters

Report with one dimension like device category (dim) and pageviews (metric) will return a total figure.

Adding certain secondary dimensions like age and gender to the above and you will return only a subset of the results, those that have valid age and gender information. Rows where no age and gender information is present are not returned. This of course leads to a loss of information.

This is quite annoying. Is there anyway to return the NULL values also?

Answer (score 4):

Google analytics returns the data it has.   If it doesn't have the data then no data will be returned.

No there is no way to return the so called NULL values for rows missing data.

Comment: If I have a report with Dims: 'Device category', Age and Metric:  pageviews. GA will actually drop the rows containing valid row information where age='NULL' but theres a valid pageview value for device category. This in fact represents data not being returned.

Comment: This is how Analytics database works.   This isn't a relational database.    If one of the dimensions has no value then it wouldn't meet the requirements of your request.

Comment: Trying Googleing multi dimensional database if you are interested

Comment: Glad I found out this limitation now. Guess I wont be upgrading to GA Premium anytime soon!